# Starting unix background process maintaining the order

Tags: shell, unix, nohup

I have a script which starts many processes in background and uses nohup to make sure these processes keeps on running -

```
nohup "./$__service_script1.pl" $__service_args < /dev/null > /var/log/$__service_name.log 2>&1 &
```

The problem is its important for me to make sure that processes starts in the order of their invocation. Is their a way to wait until the process has definitely started before attempting to start another process?

I tried wait, but it waits till the process is finished, I just want to make sure that process has started. Probably the simplest solution would be to put sleep for a few seconds in between processes, is there a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Another naive solution would be to poll `ps | grep $__service_name` for the relevant entry, being careful not to get the `nohup` one.  Or you could add an extra level of bootstrapping by creating a program to fork and start a service, wait for the PID to show up, then notify your initialisation script.  Bear in mind that as soon as one of your services needs to be restarted, it will be out of order.  This could even happen during initial startup.

Comment: Call them from one _umbrella_ master script and only NOHUP the master script? (or concatenate them all and call the whole bunch. Or chain them)

Comment: would that work, does calling them from one master script and nohup master script make sure that the processes started from that script do  not die after exiting this script ? Have to try this solution.

Comment: You could write a zero-length file in the service script (a la pid files used by daemons) and have the master script wait until that file exists (most simply by polling), then unlink it and start the next process.

Comment: @wildplasser just curious, for the way you suggest, are the processes created by that master script safe from hang-up signal? It seems not to me (but I am not sure)

Comment: Why don't you try? IMHO: they are not safe from the signal, but the signal will not be sent to them by their parent (the master script and the nohup process above it)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "definitely started".  If you mean that fork(2) has completed and the new process exists, then each process is started by the time nohup returns.  A new process has been created.

The problem you are running into is that there is no guarantee how long the nohup'ed process gets to run before the shell returns.  When the process you start is "definitely started" depends on what the process does for initialization.  If you do not have source of the applications or are not able to modify them for some other reason, you will be limited to looking at their output.  Many daemons will output a log message at various stages of their initialization.  You can modify your script to

1. Look for a log file, and create an empty one if it does not exist
2. Open the log file for reading (at the end to avoid false messages from previous invocations), watching for the log message that indicates the process has started,
3. Start your process with nohup,
4. Wait for your log file watcher

In bash, it would look something like this might work (this code is completely untested):

```bsh
log=<path to log file>
msg=<message service prints when it is ready>
svc=<path to service>

# Create log file if it does not exist
if [ ! -f "$log" ] ; then
     echo > "$log"
fi

# watch for message to appear on a single line in the log file 
tail -0 -f "$log" | egrep "$msg" | head -1 &
ready_pid=$!

# Start the service
nohup "$svc"  < /dev/null >> "$log" 2>&1 &

# Wait for the message
wait $ready_pid
```

You want to start watching the log file before forking the service, because otherwise, the message might go by in the log before the script starting the service can attach to the log file.